# IDE yelling about CSS @media query

Tags: css

[image: screenshot of some of the errors in my code]

My CSS code has suddenly been identified as having problems in my IDE. When I tried adding media queries to make my website responsive, it is making things such as colons and curly brackets have errors. I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The **brackets** are not the problem. You just forgot to add the `and` keyword to your `media` query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
/*  Your code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your media query:

```css
@media screen (max-width: 750px) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Is incorrect. The correct media query is as follows:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Note the `and` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Remove *screen* it is not necessary. If you are only wanting to apply primarily to screens then add the word *and* after screen.

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
```

or

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
```